# While running PEX getting error

Tags: pex

First of all - awesome job on PEX !!!

We are trying to do code explorations for one of our Office Add-In project. So, first of all let me ask yo this - Is this is feasible ? In other words can PEX help me with Add-In/VSTO projects ?

Secondly, I trying to execute PEX on one of our Add-In methods and got the following error

--- Description 
runtime context Microsoft.Pex.Engine.Libraries.MicrosoftVisualBasicLibrary+ProjectErrorRuntimeContextAttribute+Context failed to open

runtime context Microsoft.Pex.Engine.Libraries.MicrosoftVisualBasicLibrary+ProjectErrorRuntimeContextAttribute+Context failed to open

--- Exception details

System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.      at System.Void Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.ProjectData..ctor() 
      at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.ProjectData Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.ProjectData.GetProjectData() 
      at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ErrObject Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.Err() 
      at System.Void Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.ProjectData.ClearProjectError()

Any help is appreciated !!!

Thanks,
Mrunal Buch

Comment: I've found the same error in this exact moment. I'll try to see if it is blocking the normal pex operations.

Answer (score 2):

I saw the same InvalidProgramException issue recently when running Pex. I had been able to run Pex successfully earlier, without any issues. I uninstalled the Windows security update KB2742595 and that fixed the issue. I do not see the InvalidProgramException from CLR any more.

For reference, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578355/system-invalidprogramexception-when-executing-unit-tests-in-mstest-after-microso) is a similar issue with the security update and the MS unit test framework.