# !error! [execution] runtime context during PEX exploration

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-7, pex

I have the following during PEX exploration:

!error! [execution] runtime context Microsoft.Pex.Engine.Libraries.MicrosoftVisualBasicLibrary+ProjectErrorRuntimeContextAttribute+Context failed to open

[symbols] could not load symbols for C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualBasic\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

[symbols] search path: ;

!error! [execution] runtime context Microsoft.Pex.Engine.Libraries.MicrosoftVisualBasicLibrary+ProjectErrorRuntimeContextAttribute+Context failed to rollback

I tried fixing this problem by uninstalling a couple of software updates (as explained in [While running PEX getting error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15134692/while-running-pex-getting-error)) but unfortunately the problem still remains.

Have anyone find a solution to this?

Best regards,
JP

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! No need to add your signature - your user card is automatically placed below your posts.

Answer (score 1):

I got same error.
At that time, I replaced .NET 4 with .NET 4.5.
After that, pex run successfully then.
Please try.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can tell Pex not to instrument the VisualBasic assembly, if you do not need it.

Place the following line into PexAssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: PexInstrumentAssembly("Microsoft.VisualBasic", InstrumentationLevel=PexInstrumentationLevel.Excluded)]
```